# Aws lambda how to use/mention aws api gateway in serverless.yml

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless

I'm learning aws lambda (creating some rest apis, apply rate limiting). I have read some examples from aws and they said that we need to create/use aws API gateway to route to lambda function (UI based)

But I also found in the internet this serverless.yml. No need to use UI anymore

```
functions:
  simple:
    handler: handler.simple
    events:
      - httpApi: 'PATCH /elo'
  extended:
    handler: handler.extended
    events:
      - httpApi:
          method: POST
          path: /post/just
```

You guys can see there is no where that mention about api gateway. So my questions are:

1. If I use configuration like that, how can I know whether it is using API gateway or not? If not, how can I specify it to use API gateway?
2. Is Lambda-Proxy or Lambda Integration used in this case ([read more here](https://medium.com/@lakshmanLD/lambda-proxy-vs-lambda-integration-in-aws-api-gateway-3a9397af0e6d))? How can I specify it to use Lambda Integration?
3. Is aws API gateway suitable for rate limiting? Like allow only 1000 request per user (bearer token) per 120 minutes.

Since I'm still waiting for aws account, I have no environment to test. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: How do you know if it is using API Gateway? Read the Serverless Framework documentation for the [httpApi event](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/http-api). Note that Serverless Framework is trying to make your life simpler by abstracting away some of the AWS building blocks. If you create a function in your serverless YAML then sls creates a Lambda function. If you supply an event configuration, sls creates an API Gateway endpoint and integrates it with your Lambda function. If your event handler is httpApi, that integration is always proxy integration.

Comment: On the topic of per-client rate throttling, read the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-request-throttling.html). That's only available with usage plans. Otherwise rate limiting is per account, per region, per API, per stage, and per method, not per client.

Comment: @jarmod is there anyway to add custom rate limiter based on client credentials?

Comment: Within API Gateway, usage plans and quotas, as alluded to earlier. Anything else would be custom (see [related example](https://cloudonaut.io/customized-rate-limiting-for-api-gateway-by-path-parameter-query-parameter-and-more/)).

Comment: Thank @jarmod, your example is really helpful. I suppose that we can configure it in serverless.yml like https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/http-api#lambda-request-authorizers , right?

Comment: I would assume so, but you should verify. It doesn't seem to use anything that sls framework doesn't support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's establish that there are two different types of endpoints in API Gateway: REST APIs and HTTPS APIs. These offer different features and customization. For example, REST APIs offer client-level throttling, whereas HTTPS APIs do not. You can see more information about both versions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-vs-rest.html).

1. This configuration would create a new HTTPS API gateway endpoint. When you specify that the event triggering the lambda is a post to that specific path, your deployment will create a new endpoint with API gateway to enable that automatically.
2. The serverless framework allows you to specify whether or not you want to use a REST API or an HTTPS API. The syntax above is for the HTTPS API -- also referred to in serverless' documentation as [v2](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/http-api), which by default only supports lambda-proxy. You can opt to use a REST API which can be configured to use either, as you can see reading through the [documentation here](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway)
3. You can enable throttling on REST APIs as shown in the (documentation)[3](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway):

   ```
    service: my-service
    provider:
      name: aws
      apiGateway:
        apiKeys:
          - myFirstKey
          - ${opt:stage}-myFirstKey
          # you can hide it in a serverless variable
          - ${env:MY_API_KEY}
          - name: myThirdKey
            value: myThirdKeyValue
          # let cloudformation name the key (recommended when setting api key value)
          - value: myFourthKeyValue
            description: Api key description # Optional
            customerId: A string that will be set as the customerID for the key # Optional
        usagePlan:
          quota:
            limit: 5000
            offset: 2
            period: MONTH
            throttle:
              burstLimit: 200
              rateLimit: 100
   ```

Then in your function definition:

```
functions:
  hello:
    events:
      - http:
        path: user/create
        method: get
        private: true
```

Comment: Note that "v1" and "v2" appear to be [Serverless Framework](https://www.serverless.com/) designations. These are not AWS terms. There is no "version 1" of API Gateway and "version 2" of API Gateway. There is, instead, [REST APIs and HTTP APIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-vs-rest.html).

Comment: I appreciate the clarification, editing to avoid ambiguity

Comment: Thank you. @m.oulmakki you said "your deployment will create a new endpoint with API gateway to enable that automatically". API gateway you mention here is AWS API gateway, right?

Comment: Your serverless.yml will declare a provider - probably aws if you follow that syntax, so yes, AWS API gateway